# MySQL Select distinct values from two table that have a common key

Tags: mysql

I am making a query that is using 3 table.  the quotes table has a key called quote_id which is stored in the quote_items table.  There will only ever be one instance of quote_id in the quotes table but in the quote_items table it may occur several times.  I want to join the two together, but filter out any instance where quote_id occurs more than once.

```
SELECT *  FROM quotes 
INNER JOIN quote_items ON 
quotes.quote_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT quote_id FROM quote_items)
INNER JOIN accounts ON 
quotes.account_id = accounts.account_id AND quotes.status = 0 
WHERE primary_sales_id = 2 AND quotes.quote_id = quote_items.quote_id
ORDER BY quotes.date_submitted DESC
```

You can ignore the account_id part.  Basically my line 3 should be different, which I know, but how to go about this I'm not sure.

If I had quotes looking like this

```
quote_id | quote_name
1        | quote1
2        | qute2
```

and quote_items looking like this

```
quote_id | item_name
1        | boards
2        | nails
2        | blocks
```

I should get back

```
quote_id | quote_name | item_name
1        | quote1     | boards
2        | quote2     | nails
```

Comment: Instead of wood, you mean boards I think

Comment: Oops... yes that is correct

Comment: @user1815207 I fixed the typo wood <->boards

Comment: ... is the example data really relevant of the problem? If I understand it well, you search for a way to join two tables if the *id* appears only one time in each table?

Comment: You are correct... I edited it to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT quotes.quote_id, quote_name, item_name
FROM quotes, quote_items 
WHERE quotes.quote_id = quote_items.quote_id
group by (quote_id );
```

Comment: While I appreciate the help, this doesn't work since it will return the same quote_id more than once.  Also it would have to read quotes.quote_id on line 1 or it is ambiguous

Comment: Ok, then mysql has a "cheat" for this: add group by (quote_id ), that returns the first occurance and you don't need the above big query and it is a native way

Comment: Sorry for the delay! If this is correct mark it, so as for others to know! I think that this is faster. If it is please let us know! Thanks in advance

Comment: How does this filter out multiple quote items on the same quote?

Comment: It takes the first occurance. You can do a simple select from one table to see it more clearly

Comment: @LefterisBab. What if I need to return all the columns instead from both table without defining each column explicitly like: `SELECT DISTINCT quote_id FROM quotes, quote_items 
WHERE quotes.quote_id = quote_items.quote_id
group by (quote_id );`  This returns me only 'quote_id' as output. Can you help with this?