# How to compare two tables in SQL Server adding value to matched Employee

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server, `Table1` and `Table2`. Both tables have a column `EmployeeName` which should match almost both tables.

This is my sample data in Table 1 :

```
EmployeeName   Expenses   Bonus  overTime    
-----------------------------------------
John             198      3734     230
Ayesa              0      2384       0
Nimi             400       230       0
Michael            0       571       0
Alexander        212       240       0
```

Table 2 `Employee Name` almost has the same values - like this:

```
EmployeeName     Ermatch      Roth       
-----------------------------------
John               298         500
Ayesa                0         450
Nimi               400         250      
Michael              0         551
```

Now both tables which are the employee match both `Table 1` and `Table 2`. Finally join the one Table like this

```
 EmployeeName   Expenses   Bonus  overTime    Ermatch  Roth
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 John             198       3734    230         298    500
 Ayesa              0       2384      0           0    450
 Nimi             958        230      0         400    250
 Michael            0        571      0           0    551
 Alexander        212        240      0           0      0
```

Which are Employeename match both table  Ermatch and Roth join Table 1. how to join both table? how to compare  both Table Employeename . thanks in advance

Comment: removed incompatible `mysql` tag

Comment: ok thanks sir @Jens

Comment: Try use distinct? this is refference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931256/mysql-select-distinct-values-from-two-table-that-have-a-common-key

Answer (score 2):

also you can join both table with full join like below.it use when one Table has value but another Table hasn't this value .

```
;WITH Tab1( EmployeeName,Expenses,Bonus,overTime)
     AS (                         
     SELECT 'John'     ,    198   , 3734  ,   230 union all
     SELECT 'Ayesa'    ,      0   ,  2384 ,    0  union all
     SELECT 'NImi'     ,     400  ,  230  ,    0  union all
     SELECT 'Michael'  ,       0  ,   571 ,     0 union all
     SELECT 'Alexander',     212  ,   240 ,     0 
     )
     ,tab2( EmployeeName,Ermatch,Roth)
     AS
     (                      

     SELECT 'John'     ,298     ,500  Union all
     SELECT 'Ayesa'    , 0      ,450  Union all
     SELECT 'NImi'     , 400    ,250  Union all
     SELECT 'Michael'  , 0      ,551  union all
     SELECT 'Alex'  , 300      ,500
     )
     SELECT isnull(T1.EmployeeName,T2.EmployeeName) EmployeeName,
            ISNULL(T1.Expenses,0)Expenses,
            ISNULL(T1.Bonus,0)Bonus,
            ISNULL(T1.overTime,0)overTime,
            ISNULL(T2.Ermatch,0)Ermatch,
            ISNULL(T2.Roth,0)Roth 
        FROM Tab1 T1 full join tab2 t2
    ON t2.EmployeeName=T1.EmployeeName
```

Answer (score 1):

Join both table like below.This code might be usefull for your requirement

---

```
;WITH Tab1( EmployeeName,Expenses,Bonus,overTime)
     AS (                         
     SELECT 'John'     ,    198   , 3734  ,   230 union all
     SELECT 'Ayesa'    ,      0   ,  2384 ,    0  union all
     SELECT 'NImi'     ,     400  ,  230  ,    0  union all
     SELECT 'Michael'  ,       0  ,   571 ,     0 union all
     SELECT 'Alexander',     212  ,   240 ,     0 
     )
     ,tab2( EmployeeName,Ermatch,Roth)
     AS
     (                      

     SELECT 'John'     ,298     ,500  Union all
     SELECT 'Ayesa'    , 0      ,450  Union all
     SELECT 'NImi'     , 400    ,250  Union all
     SELECT 'Michael'  , 0      ,551
     )
     SELECT T1.EmployeeName,
            ISNULL(T1.Expenses,0)Expenses,
            ISNULL(T1.Bonus,0)Bonus,
            ISNULL(T1.overTime,0)overTime,
            ISNULL(T2.Ermatch,0)Ermatch,
            ISNULL(T2.Roth,0)Roth 
        FROM Tab1 T1 LEFT join tab2 t2
    ON t2.EmployeeName=T1.EmployeeName
```

Comment: @sripriya Is that your requirement

Answer (score 1):

If you want data in both two tables, I think what you need is `FULL JOIN`

```
DECLARE @Table1 as Table (EmployeeName varchar(20),   Expenses int,  Bonus  int ,overTime     int)

INSERT INTO @Table1
VALUES
  ('John',             198,     3734,    230),
  ('Ayesa',              0,     2384,      0),
  ('Nimi',             400,      230,      0),
  ('Michael',            0,      571,      0),
  ('Alexander',        212,      240,      0)

DECLARE @Table2 AS TABLE (EmployeeName varchar(20),   Ermatch   int,  Roth   int )
INSERT INTO @Table2
VALUES 
  ('John',               298,        500),
  ('Ayesa',                0,        450),
  ('Nimi',               400,        250),     
  ('Michael',              0,        551),
  ('NewUser',              0,        551)

SELECT  COALESCE (t.EmployeeName, t2.EmployeeName) AS  EmployeeName,
      ISNULL(t.Expenses,0) AS Expenses, 
      ISNULL(t.Bonus,0) AS Bonus, 
      ISNULL(t.overTime,0) AS overTime, 
      ISNULL(t2.Ermatch,0) AS Ermatch, 
      ISNULL(t2.Roth,0) AS Roth
FROM @Table1 t
FULL JOIN @Table2 t2 ON t.EmployeeName = t2.EmployeeName
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/VKJT88878